# Primeng12 Table with virtual scroll + lazyload + checkbox selection

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I have an old v12 angular/primeng based app that I am trying to retro fit checkbox selections on a table with virtual scrolling and lazy loading. I can initially toggle to select all the visible rows, but when performing a scroll to lazy load more items, the main checkbox header control doesnt stay selected, and the new rows that appear dont get marked as checked either.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zavyn1?file=src/app/app.module.ts

I know I am on an older primeng version, just wondering if there are any workarounds to get this functionality behaving, I did consider implementing my own checkbox selection behaviour, but that seems overkill.

I see this was tracked in an issue [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10951) which has since been fixed from v13 onwards in this [commit](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/695e4130382351e8e900d1350b730be32be6cf4d) I believe. Wondering if there is a way to override the methods on the table\checkbox header instance for the table in my stackblitz example above and bring in the patch fixes?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here. Do you want to toggle all of the checkbox  - meaning when scrolling down, it will be checked already. Or you just want the header to be checked only? Anyway, you know the reason why it doesn't get checked when scrolling down right?

Comment: Hi @Jimmy - I am expecting/wanting that when I initially toggle all selected for the first set of rows rendered and then I scroll enough to trigger a lazy load event, that the main toggle checkbox stays checked and the next set of rows rendered also get checked. But then maybe this is not the right user experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry for making a wrong assumption before. The behavior you described is how it should work.

The current version is not working as they implemented it wrong, so ver 12 won't work. Detail: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10697

But the new version is working as expected. I just forked the link from the homepage and make some changes. You can see the forked link here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablevirtualscroll-demo-p2j757?file=src/app/app.component.ts
Your original code also missed the part where you need to listen for the select/click event on the header.

If you wanted to "fix" the issue in the old version, you can just copy the patch from the new version. The code is under [`updateCheckedState`](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/b553156a26a0bbd498d3ebdb9eb7fbbfba8abaf2/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L4065)

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy, where would you suggest I could add the override for the `updateCheckedState` code in my v12 example?

Comment: it's from `TableHeaderCheckbox` class, and a public method so the easiest way is to use inheritance https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Classes_in_JavaScript#inheritance

Comment: If you can help me patch a fix in this instance you can take the bounty